# HTML/CSS to fill and Image

Tags: html, css

I have the image below - is it possible to fill it with a color (eg: the part in the triangle) using HTML/CSS?

[image]

Or can I create this shape with HTML/CSS and then fill it?

Or do I have to use a colored in image?

Would be preferable to use HTML/CSS completely or at least fill the image..

thx

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the part that you want to fill transparant then you can fill it with a color using css. If you want to create the triangle without using an image you can use SVG but that is not supported in some versions of IE (8 and older) or you can use [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw it in pretty much all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and CSS don't actually DO anything, they're just markup for how stuff should be presented. So no, you cannot edit an image using HTML and CSS only, though it is probably possible with JavaScript.

What you could do with HTML and CSS is to display an image with an alpha channel and set a background color on the element containing the image. The background color would then be displayed where the image is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

you can... Make sure the triangle part of your png is transparent and the rest white... PLace your image in a div with the same width and height as your pic and give that div a background color. Voila... Everything is white except the transparent triangle.

Good luck.

```
<div style="width:66px;height:30px;background-color:green;">
    <img src="yourimage" alt="" />
</div>
```